# How to used dots three times with css around image how to manage on mobile

Tags: html, css

I am working on project with VueJS add vutify I have created a component with cards that include two cards. I should display dots around cards on two different versions, one for desktop and  one mobile:

Until now, I have achieved to display dots for desktop.

I have created  dots on bottom and left for desktop by UX/UI.
Into v-card component, I have given position relative v-image as parent and dots position absolute as child.
after  that, I have styles with CSS.
I have used   background-image: radial-gradient(#F1191D 20%, #ffffff00 20%); to create dots.
I am sharing my code, what I have created until now for version desktop/ Feel free to testing it on codepene

```css
.v-image__image {
        z-index: 0;
    }
    .v-image {
        overflow: initial;
        width: calc(100% - 20px);
    }
    .dot {
        background-image: radial-gradient(#F1191D 20%, #ffffff00 20%);
        background-position: 0 0;
        background-size: 10px 10px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-repeat: repeat;
        position: absolute;
        left: -23px;
        top: -23px;
        z-index: -1;
      
}
.reds{
  background-image: radial-gradient(#F1191D 20%, #ffffff00 20%);
}
.bottom{
     top: 4px;
     bottom: 0;
     right: -19px;
     left: initial;  
     height: calc(100% + 18px);
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row>
        <v-flex md6 class="pa-4">
            <v-card>     
              <v-img    src="https://i.postimg.cc/KzhTN7KJ/Group-16.jpg" class="hidden-sm-and-down  position-relative overflow-visible "><div class="dot reds bottom"></div></v-img>    
                                    <v-img  src="https://i.postimg.cc/MG62jN5D/Group-17.jpg" class="hidden-md-and-up position-relative"><div class="dot reds bottom"></div></v-img>           
    </v-card>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex md6  class="pa-4">
               <v-card>     
                  <v-img    src="https://i.postimg.cc/KzhTN7KJ/Group-16.jpg" class="hidden-sm-and-down  position-relative overflow-visible "><div class="dot reds bottom"></div></v-img>    
     <v-img  src="https://i.postimg.cc/MG62jN5D/Group-17.jpg" class="hidden-md-and-up position-relative"><div class="dot reds bottom"></div>
     </v-img>           
      </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout> 
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

At the same logic styles, I should to create dots for  version mobile, but this time I should to used three times  dots on top-bottom any idea how I can create might with pseudo selector CSS :before or after.? Any idea?
Version for mobile should to be exactly by figma:

[image]